# What does B. V. Bowden mean by unearned umlaut and Teutonic in his book, Faster than Thought?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, turing-machines

This question is more about history of computing and perhaps in particular about Alan Turing's entry in B. V. Bowden's book, *Faster than Thought* (1953). An indexed entry in the book reads thus (emphasis mine):

> Türing Machine: In 1936 Dr. Turing wrote a paper on the design and the limitations of computing machines. For this reason they are sometimes known by his name. *The umlaut is an unearned and undesirable addition, due, presumably, to an impression that anything so incomprehensible must be Teutonic*.

This quote also appears at the beginning of Charles Petzold's book, *The Annotated Turing*. In a *Nature* [article](https://www.nature.com/articles/482441a), Andrew Hodges refers to the same lines and says,

> That a book on computers should describe the theory of computing as incomprehensible neatly illustrates the climate Turing had to endure.

Why is, in Bowden's opinion, the umlaut *unearned* (is umlaut somehow *earned*)? What may be the reasons that Bowden calls Turing's treatise [*Teutonic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teutonic)?

Comment: Could this be a question for the German language stack? There is also a History of Science and Mathematics stack

Comment: Perhaps History of Science and Mathematics? Please help redirect. Thank you!

Comment: "unearned" just means that Turing is not spelled with an umlaut - there is nothing more to it than that. Bowden does not call Turing's work Teutonic - he is giving a joking explanation of why an umlaut might be wrongly added.

Comment: I am confused, @MatthewTowers. There is no ü in Turing. Bowden adds that in the entry for Turing Machine and then gives this cryptic description?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said - Turing is not spelled with an umlaut. It's not cryptic - you are trying to read something that isn't there into this throwaway joke about a spelling error.

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you please migrate it there, @FShrike? I am < 3k.

Comment: Unfortunately MSE only allows migration to physics, meta.math or cross-validated

Comment: I think this is the first time I have ever seen "Turing machine" spelled with an umlaut. Presumably, someone before Bowden must have written it with an umlaut in order for Bowden to be able to complain about the misspelling. Perhaps this was a mid-century error that faded away.

Comment: But Alan Turing is listed twice as a Contributor to the book; thus, maybe it is a joke by Turing himself.

Comment: The question is interesting and IMO must be read more as a joke that as disregard. We have to consider that [Turing  between 1945 and 1947 worked on the design of the ACE (Automatic Computing Engine) at the National Physical Laboratory (NPL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing). Thus, it must be clear that Turing's abstract model of computation has "practical" effects.

Comment: Maybe it is also worth noting that [Turing involvement into British Bombe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe#The_British_Bombe) has been only recently disclosed in full.

Answer (score -2):

The German handbook and journals writing culture of mathematics produced texts, mostly unreadble, grammatically complicated  by tradition and academic fun to prevent others from understanding, and mostly overly exact with no room for readers own ideas.

This was in a sharp contrast to the Oxbridge culture in the 1920ties, that at those times adhered to Eulers 'proof by sight and left to readers intelligence' technics.

'Unearned' because Turings ideas are as simple as anything at those times, when the modern mathematics obscured most seemingly simple things by abandoning nature as the natural arena of mathematics.

In these times in Göttingen, Hilberts residence near to the State of Thüringen, there was a pun,  "der Thüringer Tür-Ringer" (Thuringian door wrestler), aimed at people from the East of the Harz mountains having problems with door handles.

Comment: I agree with you that the quotation is alluding to the stereotype of German academia/culture being convoluted. In fact, we still make references to German engineering/cars/firearms being "overengineered". But I don't quite see what your point is about Hilbert in Göttingen, apart from a tangent about umlauts.

Comment: The problem is with "Turing". Perhaps he had problems with the "ou" with his printer over the  telephon.  Only in German his "u"  is a plain Latin U, french "ou". Then you spell "like Thuringia".  Or he wanted the same ticks as Gödel.

Comment: I just looked up German wikipedia. Turing is a German family of artists from Swabia and the name varies indeed in writing. Türing is one of them, a family famous for their architectual style in Innsbruck around 1500.   https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BCring_(K%C3%BCnstlerfamilie)

Comment: Also, what does he intend to convey by "Teutonic"? I know from Caesar's time, germanic people were called by that name. Is that somehow intended?

Comment: Cimbers and Teutons were two tribes known to the Romans by their cruelty and wildeness. They threatend to destroy the Roman republic and both Gallias around 100 BC and were exstinct totally together with their families by Marius, Cesars uncle. The contrast is Tacitus who, even after the catasrrophe of Varus in 9 AD,  praised their virtue. and moral around 100 AD. At the  first weeks of  WWI 1914-18 the cruelties of the German troops in neutral Belgium changed the  educated peaceful Germans of Kant and Goethe into Teutons in war propaganda, difficult times began for German mathematicians .